# Left merge using pandas on 2 csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv sheets:

I am trying to find a way to merge table2 onto table1. Whenever table1 and table2 have the same Name value then replace the corresponding Price in table1 with the one found in table2 otherwise leave table1 as is.

Current code:

```
table1 = pd.read_csv('path/table1.csv', index_col=0)
table2 = pd.read_csv('path/table2.csv', index_col=0)
print(table1)
print(table2)

new_table = table1[["Name ", "ATT1", "ATT2"]].merge(table2[["Price", "Name "]], on="Name ", how="left")
print(new_table)
```

However, this leads to the following:

```
   Price  Name   ATT1  ATT2
0     12   APPL    69    81
1    900  GOOGL   303   392
2     32    INV    39     9
   Price     Name 
0   1231      APPL
1     39  FACEBOOK
   Name   ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392     NaN
2    INV    39     9     NaN
```

What i want new_table to print is:

```
   Name   ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392     900
2    INV    39     9     32
```

Comment: Please paste your data as tables/codes and not as screenshots. Also check `table1.columns` and `table2.columns` after reading your csv. Your column names may have leading/trailing spaces and not be exactly "Name"

Comment: @not_speshal thanks for your fast reply. It was an issue with Name as you thought. However i have ran into another problem as specified in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

`drop` the "Price" column from the table1 before merging:

```
new_table = table1.drop("Price", axis=1).merge(table2, on="Name", how="left")

>>> new_table
    Name  ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392     NaN
2    INV    39     9     NaN
```

As an aside, the "Unnamed: 0" columns in both your tables are likely due to the index column being unnamed in your csv files. You can avoid this by passing `index_col=0` to `pd.read_csv` like so:

```
table1 = pd.read_csv('path/table1.csv', index_col=0)
table2 = pd.read_csv('path/table2.csv', index_col=0)
```

Alternatively, only use the columns you need in the `merge`:

```
new_table = table1[["Name", "ATT1", "ATT2"]].merge(table2[["Price", "Name"]], on="Name", how="left")
new_table["Price"] = new_table["Price"].combine_first(table1["Price"])

>>> new_table
    Name  ATT1  ATT2   Price
0   APPL    69    81  1231.0
1  GOOGL   303   392   900.0
2    INV    39     9    32.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution is incredibly close, I have updated my question. Namely the first NaN becomes 900 the second NaN becomes 32.

Comment: @danielstafford - See the edit. You can use `combine_first`